# Improve performance of processing transactions in a large file

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, databases

I want to work with a table which has 296,705 transactionslines and 172,147 transactions.

```
GM = Import["E:\\mathematica\\data\\dataset.txt", 
  "Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> "|", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII", 
   "EmptyField" -> "", "RepeatedSeparators" -> False, 
   "HeaderLines" -> 1, 
   "DateStringFormat" -> {"Day", "-", "Month", "-", "YearShort"}, 
   "NumberPoint" -> "."}]
```

```
CITY|TRANSACTIENUMMER|TRANSACTION_LINE_NUMBER|DATE|SALE_TRANSACTION_NUM|SALES_TRANSACTION_LINE_NUM|QUANTITY|SALES_AMOUNT|DESCRIPTION|COLOR
Maastricht|1|2|28-Jul-13|10000000090608|2|1|9|Re T-shirt|Neon orange
Maastricht|1|1|28-Jul-13|10000000090608|1|1|29.99|Re T-shirt|spring green
Maastricht|2|2|28-Jul-13|10000000090611|2|1|34.99|Re Trui|Peer
Maastricht|2|1|28-Jul-13|10000000090611|1|1|29.99|Po T-shirt|Multiwater
Maastricht|3|1|28-Jul-13|10000000090758|1|1|7.95|Acc Overig|Apple green 
Maastricht|4|1|28-Jul-13|20000000026765|2|1|24.99|ReT-shirt|M.L.zeegroen
Maastricht|4|4|28-Jul-13|20000000026765|3|1|29|Pe Broek|Denim
Maastricht|4|2|28-Jul-13|20000000026765|4|1|19.99|Re T-shirt|Bordeaux
Maastricht|4|3|28-Jul-13|20000000026765|1|1|2.95|J-Club|Dark green
```

If there are two or more transactionlines within one transaction, I want to compute all posible combinations. Therefore I use the following code:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Max[GM[[All, 2]]], i++,
  GM1 = Select[GM, #[[2]] == i &];
  For[j = 1, j <= Max[GM1[[All, {3}]]], j++,
    For[k = 1, k <= Max[GM1[[All, {3}]]], k++,         
      If[j < k, 
        Flatten[
          List[
            Select[GM1[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}]], #[[3]] == j &], 
            Select[GM1[[All, {3, 7, 8, 9, 10}]], #[[1]] == k &]]] >>> "GM1.CSV";]]]];
```

After 30 minutes, *Mathematica* has filled the GM1.csv file with 2,821 transactions.

When I write a script in SP/SQL, it completes this task within 30 minutes (270,303 new records).

Anyone a suggestion how to improve the *Mathematica* code?

Comment: The `GM1=Select[...]` part, called all the time seems quite expensive for me. What about sorting by transaction number first and then using `TakeWhile[]`. Afterwards directly proceed with the next one.

Comment: I've heard about 'packed array'. Anyone a idea about how to used this in relation with my code?